# How to remove changes present in current diff from another branch/diff (Arc diff & phabricator)

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist

I have 2 branches let's call them `Branch-A` and `Branch-B`.

I had a diff created on `Branch-A` let's call it `D1`. After that, I switched the branch to `B`, made some changes, did `git merge masetr`, and updated `D2`.

But my `D2` diff has changes from `Branch-A`(`D1`) & the changes are pushed to remote branches. So is there any command through which I can remove/unmerge `Branch-A` changes from `Branch-B`?

Comment: How did you generate `D2` diff _specifically_ (in terms of git command)?

Comment: I created it using `arc diff master`